# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cataloginventory.qty' - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, magento-community

I didn't change anything in the database at all and the system logged me out and when I logged back in, I get this error message:

[image]
[image]

I have tried the following with no success:

- Cleaning the cache
- Flushing the cache
- Reindexed everything
- Changed the indexer status to realtime and back to schedule
- Ran the setup:upgrade and static-content deploy command

*UPDATE Here is the table for cataloginventory_stock_item

[image]

Comment: Do you have `qty` field in `cataloginventory_stock_item` table?

Comment: @KAndy Yes I do. I have updated my question to include the screenshot of that table

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this. I'm having a similar problem.